# Transitive Closures

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let the relation $R = \{(0, 0); (0, 3); (1, 0); (1, 2); (2, 0); (3, 2)\}$
Find the Transitive closure of the relation.

So far this is what I'm coming up with:
$\{(0, 0); (0, 3); (1, 0); (1, 2); (2, 0); (3, 2); (0, 2); (1, 3); (3, 0); (2, 3); (3, 3); (2, 2)\}$

I think this is correct so far but I'm not positive that I understand the idea of the what the transitive closure entails.

Can anyone help with this or tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is **correct**.

The relation can be drawn like this, where $n \rightarrow m$ means $(n,m) \in R$:

[image]

Now, the transitive closure is the smallest relation $R'$ s.t $R \subseteq R'$ and $R'$ is transitive.

Okay, so why is our relation not transitive now? If you can, using two arrows, go from $n$ to $m$ and from $m$ to $k$, then there must be a direct arrow from $n$ to $k$:

[image]

You should convince yourself that this new relation is not transitive either.

So you simply **iterate** until you end up with a transitive relation.